# Are some low dimensional distributions known to be hard to model with VAEs?

Tags: variational-autoencoder, bayesian-deep-learning, evidence-lower-bound

I am trying to implement a toy VAE project.
My goal is to use a VAE to model the moon dataset from scikit-learn, with an extra constant (but noisy) z-dimension.

To this end I use an approximate posterior with the form of a beta distribution and a uniform prior in a 1D latent space, because essentially the data is 1D. The decoder is a NN-parameterized gaussian.

I cannot get it to work using the simple ELBO.

I tried so far :

- Increasing the number of monte carlo samples in the SGVB
- Various deterministic pretrainings which tend to raise nans
- Increasing the width or depth of the networks
- Gradient clipping
- learning rate annealing
- Remove the noise in the data and perform Batch gradient descent instead of mini-batch
- ...

I use layers of residual blocks with Tanh nonlinearities, whose outputs are $\log \alpha$ and $\log \beta$ for the encoder, $\mu$ and $\log \sigma$ for the decoder.

I am starting to wonder whether the distribution is actually hard to model, because I ran out of bugs to fix and strategies to improve training.

Are some low dimensional distributions known to be hard to model this way ?

Additionally, what obvious or non obvious mistakes could I have made ?

**ADDENDA**

Code to generate the data:

```
# Adapted from sklearn.dataset.make_moons

def make_moons(n_samples=100, noise=None):
    generator = default_rng()

    n_samples_out = n_samples // 2
    n_samples_in = n_samples - n_samples_out

    outer_circ_x = np.cos(np.linspace(0, np.pi, n_samples_out))
    outer_circ_y = np.sin(np.linspace(0, np.pi, n_samples_out))
    inner_circ_x = 1 - np.cos(np.linspace(0, np.pi, n_samples_in))
    inner_circ_y = 1 - np.sin(np.linspace(0, np.pi, n_samples_in)) - .5

    X = np.vstack([np.append(outer_circ_x, inner_circ_x),
                   np.append(outer_circ_y, inner_circ_y),
                   np.zeros(n_samples)]).T
    y = np.hstack([np.zeros(n_samples_out, dtype=np.intp),
                   np.ones(n_samples_in, dtype=np.intp)])

    if noise is not None:
        X += generator.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(3), np.diag([noise, noise, noise])**2, size=n_samples)

    return X, y

# create dataset
moon_coordinates, moon_labels = make_moons(n_samples=500, noise=.01)
moon_coordinates = moon_coordinates.astype(np.float32)
moon_labels = moon_labels.astype(np.float32)

# normalize dataset
moon_coordinates = (moon_coordinates-moon_coordinates.mean(axis=0))/np.std(moon_coordinates, axis=0)
```

**UPDATE**

I have found a mistake that can explain poor performance.

In my post I said that the data is basically 1D, yet when I create the dataset I normalize the standard deviation in every dimension. This increases the magnitude of the z noise, and all of a sudden the third dimension accounts for a lot of variance and my model tries to fit to this noise.

Removing the normalization dramatically increases the performance.

Comment: Could you please link the Moon Dataset? Is this what you are referring to? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_moons.html

Comment: Yes. I have updated the question to provide the code.

Comment: I am trying to model this using an MSE loss, in that case I do not have to standardize it. However, my model is not learning beyond a point with VAE. My Reconstruction loss staturates and somehow when sampling after training, the output is not capturing the shape of moons dataset and instead a blob. Can you share some info on the architecture of your model.

Comment: did you ever figure out a good VAE implementation of the noisy moon dataset? I am trying to embed the same noisy moon dataset into latent space so it can follow a multivariate normal distribution. I think VAE does exactly that. So I googled and came across your post. However, I am not sure the 3rd axis makes sense. Do you go from 2D initial space to a 2D latent space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a mistake that can explain poor performance.

In my post I said that the data is basically 1D, yet when I create the dataset I normalize the standard deviation in every dimension. This increases the magnitude of the z noise, and all of a sudden the third dimension accounts for a lot of variance and my model tries to fit to this noise.

Removing the normalization dramatically increases the performance.